# Label at the end of a breakable tcolorbox

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox

I use the `tcolorbox` package to draw breakable boxes across pages. I can refer to the beginning of the box with the `label` key. Is there an automatical way to refer to the (page of the) end of the box?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}
\newtcolorbox[%
  auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, 
  breakable,
  #1}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
My box begins page \pageref{begin} and ends page \pageref{end}.

\begin{mybox}[label = begin]{}
  \kant
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the OP's comments, I introduce two new keys `label begin` and `label end` to do the requested job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}

\tcbset{%
  label begin/.style={label={#1}},%          just for symmetry
  label end/.style={after upper=\label{#1}}% new end label
}

\newtcolorbox[%
  auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  breakable,
  #1}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
My box begins page \pageref{begin} and ends page \pageref{end}.

\begin{mybox}[label begin=begin,label end=end]{}
  \kant
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

The `label begin` key is just for symmetry, because it is identical to `label` itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}
\newtcolorbox[%
  auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, 
  breakable,
  #1}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
My box begins page \pageref{begin} and ends page \pageref{end}.

\begin{mybox}[label = begin]{}
  \kant\label{end}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have asked an automated way (see my updated question).

Comment: @cjorssen hmm the syntax is a bit different but is `label=begin` more automatic than `\label{end}`? I ask as I'm not sure what you'd consider an answer, does it have to be a key in the first argument?

Comment: @cjorssen How about setting `after upper=\label{end}` which actually does the same thing as David Carlisle wrote, but could be put into the option list?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm That's exactly what I want, ideally wrapped up in some `key=val` syntax such as `label begin = begin` and `label end = end`.